# How to load an image written several times at runtime in kivymd

Tags: python, kivymd

I am coding a music player in kivymd , I have a class that extracts the song metadata including the image data in bytes and write the bytes to an image file. I must do this for each song and assign the image to a FitImage class. However, the image displayed for each songs happens to be the image for the last song in the list. I need a way to fix this

The extractor class

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3


class Infos:

    def __init__(song):
        self.song = song
        self.data = None

    def extract_details(self):
        # skipped unnecessary details here
        #But it returns the title, year, genre, song_length
        return title,year,genre,song_length

    def get_image_data(self):
        tag = None
        try:
            tag = ID3(self.song)
        except:
            # does not start with an ID3 tag
            pass

        if tag is not None:
            if "APIC:" in tag.keys():
                data = tag['APIC:']
                self.data = data.data
            else:
                data_file = open("assets/images/default.png", 'rb')
                self.data = data_file.read()
                data_file.close()
        else:
            # print("No tag")
            data_file = open("assets/images/default.png", 'rb')
            self.data = data_file.read()
            data_file.close()

        return self.data

    def write_image(self):
        try:
            image = open("assets/images/album_art.png", "wb")
            image.write(self.get_image_data())
            image.close()
            #print("saved")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

In the function resposible for updating FitImage with the exctracted image

```
def populate_music_tab(self, content_cls):
    """fuction for adding music in a gridlayout"""

    music_list = os.listdir("assets/sample-songs")
    
    item_holder = content_cls.ids.song_holder  #MDGridLayout
    
    for song in music_list:
        info = Infos("assets/sample/songs/"+song)
        title, yr, gnr, length = info.extract_details()  # get the song details
        info.write_image() # write the image first before loading
        
        image_src = "assets/images/album_art.png"

        item = CustomListItem()  # MDCard with FitImage,Labels and Buttons
        item.ids.song_name = title
        item.ids.year = yr
        item.ids.song_length = length
        item.ids.image_left = image_src  # FitImage

        holder.add_widget(item)
```

> The code above does this
> [image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IyM1.png)

> This is what I want to achieve that each item displays its own unique image present in the song metadata
> [desired image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjWeG.png)

Comment: Are you asking why always using the same image filename overwrites that file every time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The issue here is , when the image is overwritten for that current song in the loop I want it set to the FitImage for that current song. In my method all the songs use the image data of the last song in the list. I have edited the post with images to see what I mean